# Computing average precision metric and cost function for object detection task using scikitLearn and Tensorflow

Tags: scikit-learn, tensorflow, object-detection, average-precision

I have a Data set that contains 5 thousand pictures of my object of interest and 5 thousand pictures with out it. I trained a Convolutional Neural Network using Tensor Flow to detect the position of that object.
The output vector of my network is **[p, x, y, w, h]** where p is the probability of the object within the image and x , y , w , h values define the bounding box

The cost function that I am using looks as follows:

```
cost_pos = tf.multiply( y[:,0],tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(predictions,y),1))
cost_neg = tf.multiply(tf.subtract(1.0,y[:,0]),tf.squared_difference(predictions[:,0],y[:,0]))  
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.add(cost_pos,cost_neg))
```

where ***predictions***  is the output of the network and ***y*** is the ground truth label.

In order to measure the performance of the model I need to compute the mean average precision. So ,I implemented this helper function:

```
def AP(y,y_hat):

    y_scores = y_hat[:,0]
    y_hat_bbox = y_hat[:,1:]
    y_bbox = y[:,1:]
    y_true = np.zeros(y_scores.shape[0])

    for i in range(y_true.shape[0]):
        y_true[i] = iou(get_corners(y_hat_bbox[i]), get_corners(y_bbox[i]), True)

    AP = average_precision_score(y_true = y_true, y_score = y_scores)
    return AP
```

Note: average_precision_score corresponds to: [The scikit Learn implementation of Average Precision](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html)

But I am not sure if this is a correct implementation of it, and if this value is really representative of the performance of my model, and also it my cost function is correct or not, or if I should simply use a mean squared error for this task.